# Find the largest $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|{\sqrt{x - x^2} - 0}| \lt\epsilon$ when $1 - \delta \lt x \lt 1$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x - x^2}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. I found $L= \displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow1,x\leq1}=0$. Now the problem asks the following:

Given a small number $\epsilon \gt 0$, find the largest $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|{f(x) - L}| \lt\epsilon$ when $1 - \delta \lt x \lt 1$.

I started by saying

$$-\epsilon \lt \sqrt{x - x^2} - 0 \lt \epsilon$$

Then I squared both sides and solved both sides of the inequality simultaneously to get 
$$1 - \epsilon^2 \lt x \lt \epsilon^2$$

I don't think I'm doing this right, though, and I know the final answer is supposed to be:

$$\delta = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \sqrt{1 - 4\epsilon^2}) = \frac{2\epsilon^2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4\epsilon^2}}$$

Comment: Are we assuming that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$f(x) = \sqrt{ 1/4 - (1/2-x)^2},$$hence $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,1/2)$ and strictly decreasing on $(1/2,1)$ (because the quadratic inside the square root has this property, and square root is monotone). So if $\epsilon$ is less than $f(1/2) = 1/2$, the largest $\delta$ that satisfies the condition is the one that restricts you to the interval $(y,1)$, where $y>1/2$ and $f(y) = \epsilon$. Now the answer comes from solving $f(y) = \epsilon$, then setting $\delta = 1-y$. I advise drawing a diagram to fully convince yourself this all works.

Answer (score 1):

The geometric argument given in another answer is simpler, but here is an algebraic argument:

For $0<x<1$, $\sqrt{x-x^2}<\epsilon \iff x-x^2<\epsilon^2\iff x^2-x>-\epsilon^2\iff(x-\frac{1}{2})^2>\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon^2$

$\iff \left|x-\frac{1}{2}\right|>\sqrt{\frac{1-4\epsilon^2}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-4\epsilon^2}}{2}$ $\;\;$(for $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$)

$\iff x<\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\epsilon^2}}{2}$ $\;\;$ or $\;\;$$x>\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\epsilon^2}}{2}$.

Therefore $\delta=1-\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\epsilon^2}}{2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\epsilon^2}}{2}$ is the largest value of $\delta$ so that

$1-\delta<x<1\implies\sqrt{x-x^2}<\epsilon$ $\;\;$
(assuming $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$).

Answer (score 0):

$$|x-1|\lt \delta\Rightarrow 1-\delta \lt x \lt 1, x \lt 1$$

$$1-\delta \lt x\Rightarrow 1-x\lt \delta$$

$$\begin{align}x&\lt 1\\1-x&\lt \delta\\x(1-x)&\lt 1\cdot \delta\\ \sqrt{x(1-x)}&\lt \sqrt\delta \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow \delta \lt  \epsilon^2\end{align}$$

Numerical check: $\epsilon=0.1\Rightarrow \delta=0.01$; for any x value within 0.01 lesser than 1, $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is within less than 0.1 from zero.